# Unable to save password for autofill in iOS angular app

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, autofill

I have enabled capabilities like: associated domains and autofill credentials provider. apple-app-site-association is configured in my domain, and the AASA Validator has validated the domain.

My html looks like this:

```
<form role="form" name="loginForm" novalidate
      ng-submit="$login.Authenticate()" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="model.username" 
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="{{'and_msg_enterUsername'|translate}}"
           ng-required="true" 
           maxlength="50" autocomplete="username" />

    <input type="password"
           ng-attr-type="{{ $login.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}"
           ng-change="$login.ischanged = true;"  
           name="password" class="form-control"
           placeholder="{{'and_msg_enterPassword'|translate}}"
           ng-model="model.password" 
           ng-required="true" maxlength="255"
           autocomplete="current-password" />
</form>
```

But the app is unable to save password for autofill. Am I missing something?